# Suricata && HTTPS

Tags: веб-программирование, безопасность

Коллеги, а подскажите, пожалуйста, работает ли Suricata с HTTPS трафиком?

Answer (score 1):

Из документации: "The HTTP-port for example is 80 while 443 is the port for HTTPS and MSN makes use of port 1863."

Данные, передаваемые по протоколу HTTPS, "упаковываются" в криптографический протокол SSL или TLS.

Из документации:
Suricata adds a few protocols : http, ftp, tls (this includes ssl), smb and dns (from v2.0).

Comment: Черт. Не могу понять, как настроить сури понимать зашифрованный трафик. Явно же куда-то в кофигах или правилах нужно засунуть сертификат и ключ. Есть мысли/идеи на этот счет?

Comment: Возможно это вам поможет: https://home.regit.org/2012/08/tls-fingerprint-store/